# VBA For Each in Array type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the following code to send out emails, but I get a "run time error 13" when there is only one value in column M.

It works fine if I have more than two values. Any help please?

```
Sub testDemo()
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim Region
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Mailaddr As String
    Dim MyRange As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long


     ' Create email
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Update with your sheet reference
    With Sheets("Escalate")

    lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Range("M65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:I" & lastrow)

    End With

    arr = Range("M2:M" & lastrow2).Value


    For Each Region In arr

    myrangename = Worksheets("email").Range("C2:D200")
    Mailaddr = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Region, myrangename, 2, False)

    On Error Resume Next


    With outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            ' Add table to Email body
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "script Tracking"
            .cc = "Pearson.S@cambridgeenglish.org; Tracking.S@cambridgeenglish.org"
            .HTMLBody = "Dear Team," & "<br><br>" & _
            "blahblah  " & "<br><br>" & _
            GenerateHTMLTable(rng, CStr(Region), True) & "<br><br>" & _
            "Many thanks in advance " & "<br><br>" & _
            "Kind regards "

            .To = Mailaddr
            .Subject = "Region " & Region & " Outstanding scripts -  " & Range("L1")
            .Display

        End With
skip:

    Next Region


End Sub

Public Function GenerateHTMLTable(srcData As Range, Region As String, Optional FirstRowAsHeaders As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim InputData As Variant, HeaderData As Variant
    Dim HTMLTable As String
    Dim i As Long



    ' Declare constants of table element
    Const HTMLTableHeader As String = "<table>"
    Const HTMLTableFooter As String = "</table>"

    ' Update with your sheet reference
    If FirstRowAsHeaders = True Then
        HeaderData = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(srcData.Rows(1).Value2))
        InputData = Range(srcData.Rows(2), srcData.Rows(srcData.Rows.Count)).Value2
        ' Add Headers to table
        HTMLTable = "<tr><th>" & Join(HeaderData, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"


    End If

    ' Loop through each row of data and add selected region to table output
        For i = LBound(InputData, 1) To UBound(InputData, 1)
        ' Test Region against chosen option
        If Region = InputData(i, 9) Then
            ' Add row to table for output in email
            HTMLTable = HTMLTable & "<tr><td>" & Join(Application.Index(InputData, i, 0), "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"


        End If


Next i


    GenerateHTMLTable = HTMLTableHeader & HTMLTable & HTMLTableFooter

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is not a collection or an array, it is a single value - you can test this by checking `IsArray(arr)` before you run the `For Each`

There are several ways to fix this, but the fastest would be to include the line `If Not IsArray(Arr) Then Arr = Array(Arr)` before your `For Each`, to turn it into a 1-element array.

### Other points to consider:

- What is the purpose of your `On Error Resume Next`?
- What is the purpose of your `skip:` label?
- Variable `myrangename` is not defined - consider adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your Module, so that "Debug > Compile VBA Project" will catch those errors for you

Answer (score 1):

This will explain it better

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim arr

    lastrow2 = 2

    arr = Range("M2:M" & lastrow2).Value

    lastrow2 = 3

    arr = Range("M2:M" & lastrow2).Value
End Sub
```

When the `lastrow2 = 2`, `arr` holds only one cell value and hence it becomes a `Variant/(String/Double...etc depending on the value in cell M2)`

When the `lastrow2 > 2`, `arr` becomes a 2D array and hence it becomes a `Variant/Variant(1 to 2, 1 to 1)`

The above can be verified using a `Watch` on `arr` in VBA.

This is the reason why your code works when you have more than one cell.